# File "install.rdf" seems to inhibit execution

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I wrote my first Firefox addon and everything works fine. But since I wrote an "install.rdf", the script in "index.js" no longer gets executed. The installation works without complaints but just the script doesn't seem to run any more.

What could have gone wrong and how can I debug this problem?

Comment: install.rdf is for non-sdk addons. Index.js is for sdk add-ons. It seems you are mixing the two. If you were doing sdk addon, how come you needed an install.rdf?

Comment: Oops. I did not know there are non-SDK addons. Now I see it. The problem occurred when I tried to localize the description. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Ah localization is nice. If you want to see how non-sdk addons localize check out this repo: https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/html-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building Firefox SDK add-ons using `jpm` (or old `cfx`) node.js tool, `install.rdf` is automatically created, packaged into .xpi, and usually deleted after the operation. Sometimes it remains and in `jpm` you get a warning, when building (`jpm xpi`) with old `install.rdf` still in the directory:

```
JPM [warning] Using existing install.rdf. This file is usually auto-generated.
JPM [warning] Using existing bootstrap.js. This file is usually auto-generated.
```

So: modifying `install.rdf` is not your business when working with `Firefox Add-on SDK` and `jpm`.

There are:

- `Firefox Add-on SDK` add-ons,
- pure `XPCOM / XUL` add-ons (older, harder, more powerful),
- and lately: `WebExtension API` (meant to replace **both** in a year or two...).

Comment: Thanks for this reply Sagi. Does install.rdf get left when you make an xpi from jpm? If that's the case you can easily localize the install.rdf following what I did here: https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/blob/html-options/install.rdf